# DAG of airflow does not flow as intended by priority_weight and weight_rule

Tags: airflow

Airflow ver : 2.6.1
Python : 3.7
Celery Executor (1 worker)
using docker compose

The `concurrency` is limited to 1, and `weight_rule='absoulte'` is set, so the work should be done only with `priority_weight`
Not if you look at the DAG graph.

This is my code,
The code is rather long but it's a simple DAG so any reply would be greatly appreciated.

```
# I set "absolute" and concurrency=1
default_args = {"weight_rule": "absolute"}
with DAG(
    dag_id="priority_test",
    concurrency=1,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 7, 10, tz="Asia/Seoul"),
    default_args=default_args,
) as dag:
    extract_op = BashOperator(task_id="extract_op", bash_command="sleep 5")


#critical_group-> priority_weight=2
    with TaskGroup(
        group_id="critical_group",
        tooltip="critical_grouping",
        default_args={"retries": 3, "priority_weight": 2},
    ) as critical_group:
        critical_extract = BashOperator(
            task_id="critical_extract", bash_command="sleep 5"
        )
        with TaskGroup(
            group_id="critical_abc", tooltip="critical_abc_grouping"
        ) as critical_section_1:
            cr_extract_a = BashOperator(task_id="cr_extract_a", bash_command="sleep 5")

            cr_extract_b = BashOperator(task_id="cr_extract_b", bash_command="sleep 5")

            cr_extract_c = BashOperator(task_id="cr_extract_c", bash_command="sleep 5")

            cr_extract_a >> cr_extract_b >> cr_extract_c

        with TaskGroup(
            group_id="critical_123", tooltip="critical_123_grouping"
        ) as critical_section_2:
            cr_extract_1 = BashOperator(task_id="cr_extract_1", bash_command="sleep 5")

            cr_extract_2 = BashOperator(task_id="cr_extract_2", bash_command="sleep 5")

            cr_extract_3 = BashOperator(task_id="cr_extract_3", bash_command="sleep 5")

            cr_extract_1 >> cr_extract_2 >> cr_extract_3

        critical_extract >> [critical_section_1, critical_section_2]



#non_critical_group-> priority_weight=1
    with TaskGroup(
        group_id="non_critical_group",
        tooltip="non_critical_grouping",
        default_args={"retries": 3, "priority_weight": 1},
    ) as non_critical_group:
        non_critical_extract = BashOperator(
            task_id="non_critical_extract",
            bash_command="sleep 5",
        )

        with TaskGroup(
            group_id="non_critical_abc", tooltip="non_critical_abc_grouping"
        ) as non_critical_section_1:
            non_cr_extract_a = BashOperator(
                task_id="non_cr_extract_a", bash_command="sleep 5"
            )

            non_cr_extract_b = BashOperator(
                task_id="non_cr_extract_b", bash_command="sleep 5"
            )

            non_cr_extract_c = BashOperator(
                task_id="non_cr_extract_c", bash_command="sleep 5"
            )

            non_cr_extract_a >> non_cr_extract_b >> non_cr_extract_c

        with TaskGroup(
            group_id="non_critical_123", tooltip="non_critical_123_grouping"
        ) as non_critical_section_2:
            non_cr_extract_1 = BashOperator(
                task_id="non_cr_extract_1", bash_command="sleep 5"
            )

            non_cr_extract_2 = BashOperator(
                task_id="non_cr_extract_2", bash_command="sleep 5"
            )

            non_cr_extract_3 = BashOperator(
                task_id="non_cr_extract_3", bash_command="sleep 5"
            )

            non_cr_extract_1 >> non_cr_extract_2 >> non_cr_extract_3

        non_critical_extract >> [non_critical_section_1, non_critical_section_2]

    extract_op >> [critical_group, non_critical_group]
```

And this is my DAG GRAPH
[image]

I expected at least all `critical_groups` to prioritize the task
That's not true.

Comment: Which version of Airflow you are using? I just tested with 2.6.2, and all the critical tasks were executed before executing the non critical ones, it could be a bug in the older versions.

Comment: I am using Airflow ver: 2.6.1 version.
When I just looked at the 2.6.2 release note, there was nothing related.
whcih kind of executor that you use?

Comment: I tested with LocalExecutor, I will try with CeleryExecutor

Comment: I just tested with CeleryExecutor, and I had the same result, the tasks priority was respected.

Comment: When I changed the version to 2.6.3, I was also able to get the results I wanted.

You're right,there seems to have been a bug in 2.6.1. (I've looked up all the related settings in the meantime.)

Thank you very much.